# Looping through combinations of subsets of data for processing

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iterator, iteration

**I am processing sales data, sub-setting across a *combination* of two distinct dimensions.**

The first is a category as indicated by each of these three indicators `['RA','DS','TP']`. There are more indicators in the data; however, those are the only ones of interest, and the others not mentioned but in the data can be ignored.

In combination with those indicators, I want to subset across varying time intervals `7 days back, 30 days back, 60 days back, 90 days back, 120 days back, and no time constraint`

Without looping through this would create 18 distinct functions for those combinations of dimensions 3 categories x 6 time which was what I first started to do

for example a function that subsets on DS and 7 days back:

```
def seven_days_ds(df):

    subset = df[df['Status Date'] > (datetime.now() - pd.to_timedelta("7day"))]
    subset = subset[subset['Association Label']=="DS"]
    
    grouped_subset = subset.groupby(['Status Labelled'])
    status_counts_seven_ds = (pd.DataFrame(grouped_subset['Status Labelled'].count()))
    status_counts_seven_ds.columns = ['Counts']
    status_counts_seven_ds = status_counts_seven_ds.reset_index()
    
    return status_counts_seven_ds #(the actual function is more complicated than this).
```

And then repeat this, but changing the subset criteria for each combination of category and time-delta for 18 combinations of the variables of interest. Obviously, this is not ideal.

Is there a way to have a single function that creates those 18 objects, or (ideally), a single object whose columns indicate the dimensions being subset on? ie `counts_ds_7` etc.

Or is this not possible, and I'm stuck doing it the long way doing them all separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use :

```
def crossubsets(df):
    labels = ["RA", "DS", "TP"]
    time_intervals = [7, 30, 60, 90, 120, None]
    group_dfs = df.loc[
        df["Association Label"].isin(labels)
    ].groupby("Association Label")

    data = []
    for l, g in group_dfs:
        for ti in time_intervals:
            s = (
                g[g["Status Date"] > (pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timedelta(ti, "d"))]
                if ti is not None else g
            )
            data.append(s["Status Labelled"].value_counts().rename(f"counts_{l}_{ti}"))

    return pd.concat(data, axis=1) #with optional .T to have 18 rows instead of cols
```

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant work! Thank you! Marvelous job!